# Javafx web browser

Tags: javafx

I am trying to add a history , backward and forward buttons that actually do there jobs , so the history opens a drop down menu that shows the links the user went to and provided with a clear button to delete them if wanted and the backward to move back and the forward to go the the page the user was on.

```
public Test4(){  
    initComponents();  
}  

public static void main(String ...args){  
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {  
        public void run() {  
            final JFrame frame = new JFrame();  

            frame.getContentPane().add(new Test4());  

            frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(640, 480));  
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);  
            frame.setVisible(true);  
        }  
    });     
}  

private void initComponents(){  

    jfxPanel = new JFXPanel();  
    createScene();  

    setLayout(new BorderLayout());  
    add(jfxPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);  

    swingButton = new JButton();  
    swingButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {

                public void run() {
                    webEngine.reload();
                }
            });
        }
    });  
    swingButton.setText("Reload");  
    add(swingButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);  
}     

private void createScene() {  
    PlatformImpl.startup(new Runnable() {  

        public void run() {  

            stage = new Stage();   
            stage.setTitle("Hello Java FX");  
            stage.setResizable(true);  

            Group root = new Group();  
            Scene scene = new Scene(root,80,10);  
            stage.setScene(scene);  

            browser = new WebView();
            webEngine = browser.getEngine();
            webEngine.load("http://www.google.com");

            ObservableList<Node> children = root.getChildren();
            children.add(browser);                     

            jfxPanel.setScene(scene);  
        }  
    });  
}
```

}

Comment: What is your actual question? What have you tried? What fails?

Comment: I am still a beginner in javafx so i don't know how to create buttons or actions

Comment: Start [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javase-clienttechnologies.htm). Specifically: [buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/button.htm#CJHEEACB) and [event handling](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/events-tutorial/events.htm#JFXED117)

Comment: I do not recommend writing mixed Swing/JavaFX applications when you are just beginning JavaFX development -> write using JavaFX classes only and do not import any classes from `javax.swing` or `java.awt`.  Mixing Swing and JavaFX is a more advanced than basic topics like how to create a button in JavaFX.

Comment: My problem is not creating the button my problem is the action that the button do